# Self hosted Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) application and IIS using 443 on different IPs

Tags: https, iis, port-number

I have a server that has self hosted WCF application and IIS installed.  Server has two IPs assigned.

Is it possible to have the WCF application use 443 on IP1 and IIS use 443 on IP2?

WCF binds to all available IPs but you can use

```
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=IP:port
```

to change the binding.  From what I understand, IIS binds to all available IPs as well and it uses the same command?